# What is the command to open a new tab in Terminator?

Tags: command-line, terminator

In [Ubuntu terminal](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/command-line-for-beginners#3-opening-a-terminal), the command to open a new tab of the terminal is

```
gnome-terminal --tab
```

What is the equivalent for [Terminator](https://terminator-gtk3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

I have tried

```
terminator --tab
```

and

```
gnome-terminal -T
```

but these commands do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Terminator documentation](https://terminator-gtk3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advancedusage.html#command-line-options), the command to run to open a new tab of Terminator is

```
terminator --new-tab
```